# Distribution VS function

Tags: distribution-theory

I'm a bit confuse with something, when we say that $$\Delta f(x)=\delta _{0},$$
I know that it mean that for all $\varphi \in \mathcal C_0^\infty (\mathbb R)$, $$\int_{\mathbb R}\varphi \Delta f=\varphi (0).$$

I'm not really sure how to interpret this.  Is the idea behind is $\Delta f(x)=0$ if $x\neq 0$ and $\Delta f(0)=\infty $ ? And thus $\Delta f(x)=0$ p.p. or absolutely not ?

Comment: Well, the first thing to consider is that distributions are functionals rather than functions, i.e. they take a function space as their domain rather than a scalar field. Distributions are then a special class of functionals which satisfy certain continuity properties. Consequently, your expressions $\Delta f(0)=\infty$ and $\Delta f(x)=0$ for $x=0$ and $x\ne 0$, respectively, are not valid as you are taking a scalar argument as though it were a function. You really have to think of it as $\Delta f=\delta_0\implies\Delta f(\varphi)=\varphi(0)$ for all $\varphi$.

Comment: You can think to distributions $f$ as **limits** of sequences of functions $f_n$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\Bbb{R} f_n(x)\phi(x)dx$ converges for all $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R})$. For example $\delta$ is what we obtain with $f_n(x) = \frac{n}2 1_{|x| < 1/n}$, the limit is not a function, it is a functional.  If the $f_n$ are $C^1$ integration by parts gives that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\Bbb{R} f_n'(x)\phi(x)dx= -\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\Bbb{R} f_n(x)\phi'(x)dx$ so $f_n'$ converges to a distribution that we call $f'$.

Comment: @reuns: what is the connection between $\delta $ and $\int f_n'(x)\varphi (x)dx$ ?

Comment: That for a distribution $f$ on $\Bbb{R}^k$, $\Delta f = \delta$ means that there is a sequence of smooth functions $f_n\to f$ (in the sense of distributions) such that for all $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\Bbb{R}^k)$, $\lim_{n \to\infty} \int_\Bbb{R^k} f_n(x)\phi(x)dx=<f,\phi>$ exists, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\Bbb{R^k} \Delta f_n(x)\phi(x)dx=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\Bbb{R^k} f_n(x)\Delta\phi(x)dx = \phi(0)=<\delta,\phi>$. That $\Delta f$ is supported at the origin means you can construct a sequence of smooth functions $g_n\to f$ with $\Delta g_n=0$ away from the origin.

Comment: @reuns: Sorry, but it's not really clear... you mix/use many notation. Forget about $\Delta f=\delta $. Consider $g=\delta _0$. Does it mean that $g(x)=0$ for all $x\neq 0$ and $g(0)=\infty $ ?

Comment: Not at all, again $f,g,\Delta$ are functionals, not functions, they are limits of  sequences of functions, nothing more, nothing less. If the limit is the $0$ functional then you can think to them as functions, but around the origin you cannot think to $\delta$ as a function.

Comment: Sorry to insist and thank you for your patience (I'm a bit slow to understand...). What do you mean by $f$ is a functional, not a function ? For me a functional is a function $V\to K$ where $V$ is a $K-$vector space...

Comment: @John No, it's the opposite. A functional maps $K\to V$, where $K$ is the vector space and $V$ is the scalar field, e.g. $K=\mathcal{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})$ and $V=\mathbb{R}$. In your case, $\delta:\mathcal{C}^\infty_0(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$, $\varphi\mapsto\varphi(0)$. Essentially, $\delta(\varphi)=\varphi(0)$ is equal to a scalar value of magnitude $\varphi(0)$ at the point $x=0$ and is equal to $0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Note that in @reuns notation, $\delta(\varphi)=\langle\delta,\varphi\rangle$. Note that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:X^\ast\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ is the duality pairing in which a vector belonging to a vector space $X$ is acted on by a functional belonging to its dual space $X'$. In case $X$ is a Hilbert space, then its dual space is itself and the duality pairing is nothing other than the inner product. In this case, the dual space of $\mathcal{C}^\infty_0$ is the space of distributions $\mathcal{D}'$.

Comment: @KemalRaik: [see wikiedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)) A functional is a map $V\to K$. Btw you are exactely saying What I said ! A map $V\to K$ where $V$ is a $K-$vector space.

Comment: @John "where $V$ is a $K$-vector space"? What is a "$K$-vector space"?

Comment: @KemalRaik : A vector space on the field $K$.

Comment: @John Okay, you are correct. I misunderstood your phrasing. Yes, id est $V=V(K)$ and a functional maps $V(K)\to K$. In other words, stop taking elements of $K$ as the argument for your functional (e.g. $\delta(x)$)! The functional acts on elements of $V$ (e.g. $\delta(\varphi)$).